# How can I make dynamic variable names that are set to the strings within an array

Tags: ruby

I would like to dry up some of my code.

I have an array of strings that represent methods that I will need to call later on in my code.

```
stages = ['prospecting', 'development', 'submitted', 'committed', 'review']
```

currently, I also have 5 methods that I am explicitly naming equal to each of the values in the array

```
# returns a hash
prospecting = ElasticSearch::Job.query(
  stage: 'prospecting',
  titan_user_id: titan_user['id'],
  gte: start_date,
  lte: end_date
)

# . . .

# returns a hash
review = ElasticSearch::Job.query(
  stage: 'review',
  titan_user_id: titan_user['id'],
  gte: start_date,
  lte: end_date
)
```

I would like to do `stages.each` on the stage array and set each string as a variable name dynamically.

Something that would look like this

```
stages.each do |stage|
  [stage] = ElasticSearch::Job.query(
    stage: stage,
    titan_user_id: titan_user['id'],
    gte: start_date,
    lte: end_date
  )
end
# . . .
```

Later on in my code I will be doing things like...

```
# . . .
snapshot.prospecting_bids = prospecting['aggregations']['total_count']['value']
snapshot.prospecting_value = prospecting['aggregations']['total_sum']['value']
snapshot.development_bids = development['aggregations']['total_count']['value']
snapshot.development_value = development['aggregations']['total_sum']['value']
snapshot.save
```

is there some sort of `Variable.new = 'name'` in ruby that would allow me to dynamically loop over my array to set variable names?

my question is different than previous questions on StackOverflow because, in the examples that exist the person wanting to create a variable dynamically is just setting string values to hashes, I need to set the variable as a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better idea to use a hash or open struct:

```
require 'ostruct'
queries = stages.each_with_object(OpenStruct.new) do |stage, struct|
  struct[stage] = ElasticSearch::Job.query(
    stage: stage,
    titan_user_id: titan_user['id'],
    gte: start_date,
    lte: end_date
  )
end
```

You'll need to namespace references to `queries`:

```
snapshot.prospecting_bids = queries.prospecting['aggregations']['total_count']['value']
```

But it's very similar to your pseudocode, and avoiding metaprogramming makes the method more easily comprehendable.

If you wanted to avoid namespacing, you can make a mini-dsl:

```
queries.instance_eval do
    snapshot.prospecting_bids = prospecting['aggregations']['total_count']['value']
end
```